# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't recognise Cat B25 phone external drive

Tags: 16.04, usb, drive, cat

Ubuntu 16.04, working on a Acer Aspire V5 laptop, can not recognise a CAT B25 phone plugged in through USB port. I already checked that a computer with Mac OS can absolutely recognise it (both phone internal memory and FAT32 formatted microSD card mounted). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you believe that the phone identifies itself as a UMS device. I.e. it shows up as a drive on a computer with no specialist driver software.

If that is the case, the next step would be to see if Ubuntu can recognise other UMS drives (like USB flash drives). If it cannot then it means that the USB modules aren't compiled into the kernel, or that FAT32 support isn't in the kernel, or if they are compiled as modules are they loaded?

Typically on my system, UMS drives show up as /dev/sdb[x] or /dev/sdb[y].

Another thing you can do is as root, do a tail -f /var/log/messages, plug in a USB flash drive see what it says. Then unplug it, and then plug in the phone and see what it says.

It might also be worth doing an lspci command to verify that USB controllers are detected on the laptop.

When i plug in my Cat S30 phone into USB under gentoo I get this:

```
May  1 10:08:15 hades kernel: [11785491.087794] hub 2-0:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
May  1 10:08:15 hades kernel: [11785491.087825] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: GetStatus port:6 status 001803 0  ACK POWER sig=j CSC CONNECT
May  1 10:08:15 hades kernel: [11785491.087971] hub 2-0:1.0: port 6, status 0501, change 0001, 480 Mb/s
May  1 10:08:15 hades kernel: [11785491.114085] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: GetStatus port:6 status 001002 0  ACK POWER sig=se0 CSC
May  1 10:08:15 hades kernel: [11785491.218400] hub 2-0:1.0: debounce: port 6: total 125ms stable 100ms status 0x100
May  1 10:08:15 hades kernel: [11785491.218415] hub 2-0:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
May  1 10:08:24 hades kernel: [11785500.384411] hub 2-0:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
May  1 10:08:24 hades kernel: [11785500.384440] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: GetStatus port:6 status 001803 0  ACK POWER sig=j CSC CONNECT
May  1 10:08:24 hades kernel: [11785500.384484] hub 2-0:1.0: port 6, status 0501, change 0001, 480 Mb/s
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.410105] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: GetStatus port:6 status 001803 0  ACK POWER sig=j CSC CONNECT
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.514169] hub 2-0:1.0: debounce: port 6: total 125ms stable 100ms status 0x501
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.565335] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: port 6 reset complete, port enabled
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.565354] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: GetStatus port:6 status 001005 0  ACK POWER sig=se0 PE CONNECT
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.616423] usb 2-6: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.668338] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: port 6 reset complete, port enabled
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.668357] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: GetStatus port:6 status 001005 0  ACK POWER sig=se0 PE CONNECT
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.733749] usb 2-6: skipped 4 descriptors after interface
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.734249] usb 2-6: default language 0x0409
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.734766] usb 2-6: udev 9, busnum 2, minor = 136
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.734777] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=9091
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.734782] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.734786] usb 2-6: Product: Android
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.734791] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Android
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.734798] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: 91bcc491
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.735097] usb 2-6: usb_probe_device
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.735108] usb 2-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.735355] usb 2-6: adding 2-6:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.735486] usb 2-6: adding 2-6:1.1 (config #1, interface 1)
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.735617] usb 2-6: adding 2-6:1.2 (config #1, interface 2)
May  1 10:08:25 hades kernel: [11785500.735793] hub 2-0:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
May  1 10:08:25 hades mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-6"
May  1 10:08:25 hades mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 9 was not an MTP device
```

The phone immediately starts charging and does not show up as /dev/sdb1.

What has happened here is that the phone isn't UMS protocol at all but is fact MTP. This needs to be setup on both the linux operating system as well as the android phone.

so you will need to run:

```
apt-get install mtpfs
```

On the linux box, and then on the phone, you will need to set up the android USB option to MTP. It sounds like you may have done that already because it works on other operating systems.

I'm guessing that windows and os x supports MTP out of the box. You may have to faff around a bit with rebooting the phone before it will work, or switching USB sockets.

For further reading please see:

http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-your-mtp-androids-sd-card-on-ubuntu/